# Seeking keyboard shortcut in QGIS for opening attribute table?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut for opening an attribute table for a layer in QGIS ?

I'd like to avoid having to right-click on my layer and then use the drop-down menu to select "Open Attribute Table".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By default the **F6** key is the shortcut to open the attribute table of the layer selected in the *Layers Panel* in Windows.
If there is no default shortcut (which is the case in QGIS on MacOS) or you want to change the shortcut, you can go to *"Settings - Configure Shortcuts"* and select your own shortcut key combination.

Answer (score 11):

**In QGIS 3**:

- **F6** to open the attribute table
- **Shift + F6** to open selected features only (**S**hift like **S**elected)
- **Ctrl + F6** to open visible features only

**In QGIS 3.20**:

[image]

Source: https://north-road.com/qgis-3-0-shortcuts/

Answer (score 2):

Also, on the "Attributes Toolbar" you can click on the "Open Attribute Table" icon.